# Regex to get the license file of a github repository

Tags: c#, regex, non-greedy

From any githup-repository-page in `HTML` I try to get the path to the `License`.

Currently I got this:

```
<a\shref=\"((.*?LICENSE|.*?license)|(.*?LICENSE.+?|.*?License.+?))\">
```

> **RESULT:**

**MATCH:**

```
 73f79efa40f6bdde431853ce5ff000b9fe0b1fe5" itemprop="license" title="License.txt - <a href="/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/master/License.txt" class="js-navigation-open" id="dc5cde275269b574b34b1204b9221cb2-73f79efa40f6bdde431853ce5ff000b9fe0b1fe5" itemprop="license" title="License.txt">
```

**GROUP:**

```
/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/master/License.txt" class="js-navigation-open" id="dc5cde275269b574b34b1204b9221cb2
```

What I wanted was only:

```
"/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/master/License.txt"
```

Where is my mistake ?

> **Notes:**

I want to match:

- LICENSE.txt
- License.txt
- License
- LICENSE
- License.any
- LICENSE.any

Comment: That's called case-insensitivity. `(?i)` cluster will enable it. `(?i)<\s+href="([^"]*license[^"]*)`

Comment: How should "License.any" be treated? Is it any extension or exactly '.any' extension?

Comment: @CodeFuller could be anything like `*.lic` for example

Comment: I have updated my answer with regex that catches any (optional) extension.

Comment: @CodeFuller see my answer. Your proposal does not seem to work ;/

Comment: You haven't quoted a slash before \s, it should be '\\s' actually. Check my answer with working code.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't consider file extension in your regex and also you shouldn't include '>' at the end because there are a lot of other attributes between link and tag closure.

Also regex could be simplified if we use `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`:

```
var match = Regex.Match(text, "<a\\shref=\"(.+?license(?:\\..+?)?)\"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if (match.Success)
{
    var link = match.Groups[1].ToString();
}
```

Comment: the `.+?` after `LICENSE`/`License` already consider the extension.

Comment: @Magnetron, thank you, you're right. I've updated my answer with simplified regex.